# Where to find up-to-date redis package for 10.04?

Tags: package-management

This is a strange thing. Ubuntu is so widely used, but it is hard to find packages for popular software.

For example, when you search http://software.opensuse.org you can find a package for redis:
http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/database/openSUSE_11.4/src/

This is a good expirience.

Where to find the [latest version](http://redis.io/download) of the redis package for Ubuntu?

Comment: I've never actually installed redis via the package manager - I've always compiled it manually...

Comment: Compiling it is ok, but then you have to setup the configuration in etc, the startup/shutdown scripts, etc. I need it to be integrated with the system and easily upgrade-able.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it's not the best way, but it's what I've always done.... good question though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to find out if a [ppa](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/3940) exists is performing a [search on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=redis):

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?
```

This will show you quite a lot of sources from where you may be able to install the version you need. Simply choose an archive you trust (e.g **ppa:rwky/redis**).

Comment: Thanks, this works! Btw, how do I know who to trust? Is ppa:rwky/redis trusted?

Comment: PPAs are always "untrusted" sources. In theory you could get malicious software from such a source, luckily this seems not to happen to any significant extent.

Comment: [Chris Lea](http://about.me/chrislea) publishes a *lot* of backports to previous Ubuntu releases of very high quality: https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea

Answer (score 2):

It's actually very easy to recompile a DEB package. You can search the Ubuntu repos at http://packages.ubuntu.com or the Debian repo at http://packages.debian.org to see if there's a later version available in a newer release.

In the experimental repo of Debian, there's version 2.4.0 of the `redis-server` package, so this is how you can recompile the DEB package for Ubuntu 10.04:

1. Go to the webpage for the package in the repo: http://packages.debian.org/experimental/redis-server
2. In the right sidebar, you should see a heading *Download Source Package redis:*. Copy the link for the `.dsc` file and run:

   `mkdir ~/sources/redis` #Create a working directory for compiling

   `dget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/redis/redis_2.4.0~rc5-1.dsc`

   The `dget` command will download all three source package files from the repo, so you don't have to download them manually.
3. Extract all the sources:

   `dpkg-source -x redis_2.4.0~rc5-1.dsc` #Using dpkg-source will extract both tarballs automatically and apply the patches from Debian or Ubuntu.
4. Enter the directory of the sources:

   `cd redis-2.4.0~rc5`
5. Now compile the package:

   `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b`

   `-us` and `-uc` means that it won't try to sign the packages using a GPG key (which is unnecessary unless you are creating your own repo). `-b` means don't create the `.dsc` files and the source tarballs (since they already exist).
6. You few have you shiny new DEB files in the parent directory :)

   `cd ..`

   `ls *.deb`

Answer (score 1):

You can install it via repos:

```
sudo apt-get install redis-server
```

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lucid&searchon=names&keywords=redis

Comment: But this is version 1.2 ... The latest version is 2.4.2

Comment: But, you are comparing wrong releases between OpenSUSE and Ubuntu. 11.4 is the latest release of OpenSUSE, but you are asking for an old version of Ubuntu. Of course redis' version is so behind. If you want a more up-to-date version of redis, just check latest Ubuntu: http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/redis-server It is not latest release but you can find latest one here: https://launchpad.net/~rwky/+archive/redis

Comment: I am using 10.04 as it is the latest LTS release. It is used, so I expected to find a package. The launchpad part works, thanks!